# ABI reference ends to link error "undefined symbol" with clang , but GCC can link?

Tags: iphone, linker, clang, low-level, abi

I wish to integrate a library into my iphone project. The library source provides a makefile which builds the .a with LLVM-GCC. I use clang to build my application.

When i build my application under xcode linking my own source with the .a, LLVM-GCC succeeds to build and link my project, but clang fails while linking with this error :

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___aeabi_idiv"

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone has any idea of the origin of the problem ? I think the ABI associated to clang doesn't implement the ARM division, and GCC uses another ABI to implementing it.

I'm not yet experienced with low level optimization compilation, so can anyone help me to understand this problem ?

How can i fix this to build my app with clang ?